# Javascript promise not being returned with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have built a browser umd library using webpack.

I am listening to an onchange event of an input file. When someone submits an image/file it will convert it to base64. I am trying to make this as seemless as possible so i am using promises and await/async from https://blog.shovonhasan.com/using-promises-with-filereader/.

However, there is a problem - When i call the convertToBase64 function no response is being received. The promise is not returning a reject or resolve. There are no errors being thrown and the line with console.log(data) is not being hit.

**html**

```
<input id="hs-pay" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<script type="text/javascript">
    let hsp = new HSPay();
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
var HSFileReader = require('./helper/fileReader');


class HSPay {

    constructor() {

        this.fileReader = new HSFileReader();

        this.imageInput = document.getElementById('hs-pay');

        if (!this.imageInput) {
            throw "Error(input): hs-pay could not be found:"
        }

        this.imageInput.addEventListener("change", this.uploadImage.bind(this));

    }

    async uploadImage() {

        try {
            let data = await this.fileReader.convertToBase64(this.imageInput.files[0]);
 console.log("data", data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    }
}

module.exports = HSPay;
```

**filereader.js**

```
    class HSFileReader {

        constructor() {
            this.fileReader = new FileReader();
        }

       convertToBase64(file) {

            if (!file) {
                throw "Error(input): file could not be found:"
            }

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                this.fileReader.onerror = () => {
                    reject("Problem parsing input file.");
                };

                this.fileReader.onloadEnd = () => {
                    resolve(this.fileReader.result);
                };
            });
        }
    }

module.exports = HSFileReader;
```

Comment: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) `onloadend` is fully lowercase. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp yes that worked strange how i was not getting any errors for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), `onloadend` is a method of `FileReader`. `onloadEnd` (uppercase E) would never be called, and thus, `resolve` would never be called.